# Uploading image to a database

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to develop an android app which displays the images stored in a database hosted on a server . As of now , i'm using Firebase , which supports only text and i'm storing the url of the image to be displayed in my app .
Are there any other options for me to store images on the internet and retrieve them in my App ?

Comment: [Try following this link you might have a clue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode the images themselves using Base64 and storing them directly. But what you are doing is usually the best option.

To learn how to encode images to Base64, see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9224180/5935255

Comment: Thanks . Are there any service providers who allow us to store images in their DB for free ? Something like firebase ( but with image uploading option )

Comment: Try online hosts. Lots of PHP/SQL services offer a small storage for free.