# When converting bitmap to base64 getting black bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, base64

I  want to convert bitmap to base64 to store in sharedpreference. Whenever i am trying to convert it to base64 getting black bitmap not formatted in good shape.

Here  is Code for Converting Bitmap to base64.

```
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            b123.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

                            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Thanks for Help in Advance

Comment: see this accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224056/android-bitmap-to-base64-string

Comment: @Nitin Thakor check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are compressed image in JPEG please use PNG and try to convert in base64.

```
 b123.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
try{
   byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
   Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
   return bitmap;
 }catch(Exception e){
   e.getMessage();
   return null;
 }
```