# How do you show Drawables from Android in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native

Ultimately I'm trying to see the icons of other apps installed on the device. The app icons can be gathered with `PackageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName)` on the Android native side, but this returns a Drawable. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon%28java.lang.String%29

How can I display that Drawable in my React Native app? Not worried about iOS cross-compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can understand, you simply want to show the app icon images in your react native view. If so, then you should follow these steps:

1. **Convert your Drawable to Bitmap**. This does involves some native code which you can find in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035869/5597641
2. **Convert the Bitmap to Base64 string**. This can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9224180/5597641
3. **Send the string to the react native side**. Say, you have the base64 string in `appIcon` variable.

You can display it using the `<Image/>` component in react native as:

```
<Image style={{height: 50, width: 50}} resizeMode={'contain'} source={{uri: appIcon}} />
```

Comment: So no use of vector xmls?